# why don't separate excel workbooks show as separate buttons on the windows 10 task bar?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

Using Windows 10, and Office 2010.

I have my Taskbar set to `never combine buttons`.

If I open two Excel workbooks, I only see one Excel button in the Taskbar.

This, to me, is silly.

**How do I have a seperate button/tab on the Windows Taskbar for every open Excel workbook?**

Comment: even when you run a new excel.exe process?

Comment: Enable "Show all windows in the taskbar" in Excel > Options > Advanced.

Comment: I can't see this option in Excel 2010 @w32sh.

Comment: Yes, that is correct @Scorpion99.

Comment: Show up here Office 2010 MSI installation. (http://imgur.com/L43kiSl)
There are too many options there...one can miss this setting easily. Checked under "Display"?

Comment: Right. I was looking for an empty checkbox @w32sh, as you wrote "Enable...", meaning the option I should be enabling is currently disabled. Add yours as an Answer, and I'll select it, :-)

Comment: It's actually the opposite. Please open Excel, go to File -> Options -> Advanced -> Display, **Enable or Check** "Show all windows in the taskbar" -> OK.

Answer (score 0):

Open Excel. From the File menu, click Options -> Advanced. Under "Display", check the option "Show all windows in the taskbar" and click OK.